# Append to outgoing e-mail on ExIM the proper way

Tags: email, smtp, exim

We are a small charity organization running ExIM for our emails. Is there a proper way to configure ExIM to append links to our facebook and twitter profiles to every outgoing mail?

I found this ExIM wiki page [Modifying message bodies](http://wiki.exim.org/FAQ/Modifying_message_bodies/Q1601), which states "you shouldn't do it" and offers as only approach using `transport filters` and external scripts.

What would you recommend?

Bonus: Would it also be possible to add the newest entry of an rss feed to the signature?

Comment: Follow the recommendation! **You shouldn't do it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the answer to your question. This is the answer: [Modifying message bodies](http://wiki.exim.org/FAQ/Modifying_message_bodies/Q1601).

Mailservers are meant for receiving, forwarding, sending and storing mail. They are **not** responsible for changing the content of the body. And even for headers there are strict restrictions where a mailserver should only modify the headers required by RFC 5321.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for our usecase?

Comment: @Framester Sure. Make it mandatory for the users to add it into their signatures in their mail client. This is where it belongs to.